# Pig tail vs SMA pcb mount connector

Tags: rf, antenna

Is there any difference in applying a 50-ohm female SMA PCB mount connector to an antenna as opposed to a pig-tail connector to a microstrip patch antenna?

The difference is in terms of the performance of the antenna, such as the resonant frequency shifting, BW, gain, axial ratio

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Impedance matching is impedance matching. So, no, technically there's no difference.

That is, unless either or both of the connectors aren't *perfectly* 50Ω impedance.